# Interpretation of a First order language and functions that map distinct sets

Tags: functions, logic, first-order-logic

I'm new to logic and I've been studying Enderton's book. From Sec. 2.2 Truth and Models we know that a structure $U$ for a first order language map each function symbol $f$ to an $n-$ary operation $f^U$ on $|U|$, that is, $f^U:|U|^n \longrightarrow |U|$.

The examples from the book are elucidative. But we know from Calculus that the domain and codomain of a function don't have to be $|U|^n$ and $|U|$ respectively, for example: the function that describes the position of a particle in three dimensional space
\begin{align}
\mathbf{r}:\, &\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3\\
&t \longmapsto \mathbf{r}(t)
\end{align}

or an even simpler example, $|U| = \{\text{oranges, apples, strawberries}\}$ and the function $p$ that assigns each one a price
\begin{align}
p:\, &\,|U| \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^+_0\\
&x \longmapsto p(x)
\end{align}
where I define $p(o)=1$, $p(a)=2$ and $p(s)=3$.

The structure $U$ defined in Enderton's book and others I looked into all say $f$ is mapped into an $n-$ary function on $|U|$ and all predicate symbols $P$ are mapped into $n-$ary relations on $|U|^n$.

How can $U$ map $f$ and $P$ into $\mathbf{r}$ and $p$? Or generally, how can $U$ map symbols into functions and relations that involve distinct sets, not just $|U|$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the standard framework of model theory is rather restrictive and often requires us to perform some annoying circumlocutions. There are various tweaks we can make to smooth things over, including allowing functions to be *partial* and introducing *sorts*.

However, from a purely model-theoretic perspective this (at first, anyways) doesn't ultimately increase the power of the theory we're developing, so we stick with the more restrictive framework for simplicity. Here's an example of the sort of circumlocution we can perform to handle the case of a partial function $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\{e, \pi\}$ which sends every nonzero integer to $e$ and is undefined at $0$:

- First, we'll whip up an appropriate domain. We could pick something natural like $\mathbb{R}$ ... but we don't have to, and in general a natural choice might not exist. So let's just go silly: our domain will be $U:=\mathbb{Z}\cup\{e,\pi\}$.
- Next, to get rid of partiality we replace our *unary function* $f$ with the *binary relation* $G_f$ (called the *graph* of $f$) describing its operation: $$G_f=\{(x,y)\in U^2: f(x)\downarrow=y\}$$ (where "$\downarrow=$" means "is defined and equal to"). Concretely, $G_f=\{(x,y)\in U^2: x\not\in\{0,e,\pi\}\mbox{ and }y=e\}$.

The structure $(U;G_f)$ then "successfully displays" at least the very basic behavior of $f$. Of course this is utterly unsatisfying for handling *other* functions, but you can see the general process at work here.

What if we want a "once-and-for-all" framework, so we don't have to constantly change our setting? Well, ultimately we can go all the way to **set theory** and implement everything in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. However, this is its own separate topic, and I don't think it's worth considering *at first*.

Comment: Since the OP explicitly mentioned the example of a function into $\mathbb R^3$, it might be good to point out that such a function can be viewed as three functions into $\mathbb R$. So although model theory allows primitive functions to have tuples in the domain, it usually doesn't allow tuples in the codomain. (+1)

Comment: ok, thanks, i see the idea. We build the union of the distinct sets, define that as $U$ and then craft a special relation that links the elements as my original functions. In case we have a vector function we split it into components as pointed by Andreas.

Comment: Would it be correct for my fruit-price function example to simply set $|U|=\mathbb{R}$ and rename each fruit as an element in $\mathbb{R}$, like $o\equiv 1$, $a\equiv 2$, $s\equiv 3$ and then $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$ and $f(3)=3$? After all I only need to be able to distinguish the fruits.